# Can we mock private fields of a class for JUnit testing?

Tags: java, junit

If some public method of a class to be tested is using private fields then can we mock that private field in JUnit test method?
Otherwise if you don;t have access to private field then you can't use or modify its values and pass it to JUnit tests to see the different results.

Comment: What do yo0u mean by "mock private fields"? Do you mean "Set a private field to be a mock?" so you have class A that has a class B as a field and you want to mock that? You can use `ReflectionTestUtils` (from spring) to inject values into private fields if that is what you are looking for. If the field is a primitive value, then it is not possible to "mock" it.

Comment: You should be testing the interface rather than the implementation anyway.

Comment: Yes.I just read somewhere about Mockito. Is this ReflectionTestUtils same as Mockito?

Comment: The rule of thumb in unit testing is that if you realize that you need to access private fields or methods, your design is bad. You should only access the public methods of a class you're testing. If you need to test private methods, then maybe they should be extracted into a separate class. You definitely **should not** write tests that require changing the value of private fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reflection (the following example is not a JUnit test, but it works exactly the same).

Example class with `private` variable and `print()` method to ensure `set` was successful.

```
public class stackoverflow2 {
    private int testPrivate = 10;
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(testPrivate);
    }
}
```

Calling class using reflection and `get` and `set` methods. Note, setting `testPrivateReflection` will not alter `testPrivate` because it's a local copy of the value, thus we use `set`.

```
public class stackoverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, 
            IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        stackoverflow2 sf2 = new stackoverflow2();
        Field f = sf2.getClass().getDeclaredField("testPrivate");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        int testPrivateReflection = (int)f.get(sf2);
        System.out.println(testPrivateReflection);
        f.set(sf2, 15);
        sf2.print();
    }
}
```